# Correct creation of a dialog alert via the long click of a recyclerview?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, listener

My question may seem special but I need your help with how I create dialog boxes for each element of a recyclerview.

Indeed my fragment contains a recycle view with X elements, and I want that, when the user presses one of the elements for a long time, a dialog box opens and asks him "Are you sure you want to delete this element?" and two buttons "Yes" and "Cancel".

I have succeeded in doing so, but I especially want to know if my way of doing it is the right way, in order to avoid acquiring bad programming reflexes.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
   PlaceViewHolder Pholder =(PlaceViewHolder) holder;
   Glide.with(mContext)
        .load(mPhotoList.get(position))
        .fitCenter()
        .into(((PlaceViewHolder) holder).mPlace);

   Pholder.mPlace.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v){
            switchContext(mPhotoList.get(position));
       }
   });

   Pholder.mPlace.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
       @Override
       public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
           new MaterialAlertDialogBuilder(mContext)
                   .setTitle(R.string.profile_photos_dialog_box_title)
                   .setMessage(R.string.profile_photos_dialog_box_message)

                   // Specifying a listener allows you to take an action before dismissing the dialog.
                   // The dialog is automatically dismissed when a dialog button is clicked.
                   .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                           // Continue with delete operation
                       }
                   })

                   // A null listener allows the button to dismiss the dialog and take no further action.
                   .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, null)
                   .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
                   .show();
           return true;
       }

   });
}
```

As you can see, every time I call onBindViewHolder I add an onClick listen and it is in this last one that I create the dialog box

Moreover, since my message is always the same, should I turn to a contextmenu, even if I find the format of this menu not very adapted to the choices and possible action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm honestly not sure what the "best practice" may be, but I've done this before. How I've done it is, instead of creating the dialog and performing the action inside the longclick handler within `onBindViewHolder`, I create a custom listener interface so I can pass 
relevant data back to the caller. Like this:

**MyListListener**

```java
public interface MyListListener {

    // Where "index" can be the index of the item, or the object represented by the list item at "index"
    void onItemLongPressed(int index);

}
```

I'll pass that into the constructor of my custom `RecyclerView.Adapter` like this:

**MyAdapter**

```java
public class MyAdapter extends ... {

    private MyListListener listener;

    public MyAdapter(MyListListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

}
```

Then inside `onBindViewHolder`
**MyAdapter / ViewHolder onBindViewHolder**

```java
Pholder.mPlace.setOnLongClickListener(new 
    View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
         public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
             listener.onItemLongPressed(position);
         }
    });
```

And then my fragment or activity will implement the listener interface:

**MyActivity**

```java
public class MyActivity extends ... implements MyListListener {

    @Override
    public void onItemLongPressed(int index) {
        // Show the dialog and do things
    }

}
```

I personally like this because it means my adapters are more isolated. They don't do much outside of showing a list of things. The logic behind those "things" ultimately lives elsewhere. It's easier to unit test this way as well, because you can mock the listener interface.

Comment: Thanks for that detailed answer !

I really like your solution, but, does mine is like "antipattern" or forbidden ??
I don't really know what to think about my solution.

Comment: The point is, that these both are already listeners - and that one can basically register them as they are; this approach here just adds the item index to the interface method (the ID of the record is often more relevant than the index, but the index is required for updating the adapter).

Comment: @MartinZeitler yes, thank you. I updated the first part of my answer to say I create a **custom** listener interface so I can **pass relevant data back to the caller**.

Comment: @Quentin I'm not sure if your approach is considered an anti-pattern, but for the sake of keeping details about what happens to the data represented by the list **out of** the list, I prefer my approach so the list's job is only to display a list of things.

Comment: @MattU when the pattern is "separation of duties"... it's an anti-pattern to add much code into an adapter.